Ampacity rating of a wire
Is the ampacity rating of a wire only pertains to the current rating? For example, if I have a 14awg wire and has a load of 10VDC/30A, is this the same as 100VDC/30A load? I understand that they will produce different power ratings, but will the wire still behave the same?

In order to have a certain current the same wire must have the same voltage drop on it. It won't "feel" the voltage drop of the load it is connected to. Not sure I am interpreting your question correctly though.

Thank you for your comments. To make it simple, I have a load of 10VDC/30A (300W) and the wire (e.g. 14awg) works perfectly fine. I plan to use this wire with a 100VDC/30A (3000W) load. Will the wire heat up or burn under these conditions, or will it continue to operate normally

To answe the post questions: Yes and no. Rated current carrying capacity of a wire is not dependent on the system voltage, but its not only dependent on the current in the wire. It also depends on the thermal environment of the wire. The copper and insulation melts at some certain temperatures, and the temperature of the wire is of course dependent both on the self-heating and the temperature and thermal capacity/conductivity of the surrounding area

So you are going to connect the whole system to a higher voltage. The most dangerous issue I can think of is that you "load" is failing, and say, short-circuiting. Then in your 100V case the wire will have much higher current and will burn/melt/catch fire.

MrGerber: So, you're saying that as long as the current flowing through the wire is the same at 10V and 100V, there won't be any issues—the power rating won't affect the wire, and the wire's temperature will remain the same for both voltages? This scenario is assuming that the test conditions between 10V and 100V is the same. Sorry for the inconvenience about this question.

The current rating of the wire specifies the maximum current it can carry while causing an also-specified (or should be) temperature rise.
The wire must be operated to stay below its maximum specified temperature, along with any maximum temperature your application requires.
The voltage rating of an insulated wire specifies the maximum voltage the insulation is to be stressed with in operation.
This allows for outside of the insulation to be in contact with anything else, such as metalwork connected to the safety earth. The insulation normally has a much higher voltage capability than its specified maximum operating voltage.

So you can use a wire at an operating voltage beyond its voltage rating provided it is away from other conductors by a suitable insulation gap. Such as held in rubber securings etc.
But in most applications this is so inconvenient. Much more importantly, when meeting electrical safety standards then insulated wires must have specific voltage ratings to meet the approvals, such unusual schemes like that couldn't get the equipment certified anyway.
All in all, use sufficiently voltage rated wire for the application. Far more often than not, there's no downsides and the cost impact is minimal or bearable.
